# When using a cache plugin I destroyed a menu structure

Tags: menus

Now I cannot add any menu entry to my main menu structure, possibly because I attempted to modify it using a cache plugin.

Anybody knows how I can fix that and make the menu editable again?

Thank you

Comment: There are far from enough details here to make a guess. Please elaborate which plugin you have used and how exactly you attempted to "modify" menus?

Comment: I used super cache plugin to add a category. This destroyed my menu. If I create a new menu, all goes well. 
Can you please point me to the answer which corresponds to this question?